# scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[UInt]?

Tags: scala, spire

Trying to make a `scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange[UInt]`

Looks like it needs a `scala.math.Integral[UInt]`.

But there does not seem to be a `spire.math.Integral[UInt]`.

I am assuming thats because `UInt` violates the laws around `Integral` in some way.

I am mostly interested in `NumericRange[UInt].contains(x: UInt)`

Is it folly for me to attempt to construct a `scala.math.Integral[UInt]` on my own?

Or should I find some other way to get `contains`?

Is there a trait that should exist that should be inherited by `Set[T]` and `Range` and `NumericRange[T]` that declares `contains[T]`

What should that trait be called?

Should I do this as a type class?

What should I call this type class?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need `contains(x: UInt)`, you should use `spire.math.Interval[UInt]`

See: https://typelevel.org/spire/api/spire/math/Interval.html

If you need other bits of the `NumericRange[UInt]` then see other answers that arrive in the future.